# Problem with logging out of the application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm having problems with logging out of the application. When I click "Logout" I get the error "undefined method` id 'for nil: NilClass. " When logging in everything works. The error is displayed on line 9.

```
 @search = Expense.where(:user_id => current_user.id).search(params[ :q ])
```

Please help.

expenses_controller.rb

```
class ExpensesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :user_id, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    # GET /expense  expense
    # GET /expense.json


    def index
      @search = Expense.where(:user_id => current_user.id).search(params[ :q ])
      @expense = @search .result 
      @search.build_condition
    end

    # GET /expense/1
    # GET /expense/1.json
    def show

    end

    # GET /expense/new
    def new
      @expense = Expense.new
    end

    # GET /expense/1/edit
    def edit
    end

    # POST /expense
    # POST /expense.json
    def create
      @expense = Expense.new(expense_params)
      @expense.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
      respond_to do |format|
        if @expense.save
          format.html { redirect_to @expense, notice: 'zostały zapisane.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @expense }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @expense.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /expense/1
    # PATCH/PUT /expense/1.json
    def update
      respond_to do |format|
        if @expense.update(expense_params)
          format.html { redirect_to @expense, notice: 'expense was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @expense }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @expense.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # DELETE /expense/1
    # DELETE /expense/1.json
    def destroy
      @expense.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @expense, notice: 'Zakupy zostały usunięte.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end

    private
      # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
      def set_expense
        @expense = Expense.find(params[:id])
      end

      # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
     def expense_params
        params.require(:expense).permit(:date, :price, :category, :where)
     end
      end
```

schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_08_26_203551) do

  create_table "expenses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "date"
    t.decimal "price"
    t.string "category"
    t.string "where"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_expenses_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "searches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "min_date"
    t.date "max_date"
    t.string "category"
    t.decimal "min_price"
    t.decimal "max_price"
    t.string "where"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  root 'expenses#index'
  get 'search/search'
  get 'expenses/search'
  resources :expenses
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `current_user.id` in the query. Once you logout `current_user` is nil, so you can't call `id` on it.

You have several options:

- restrict access to expenses for only logged in users
- call current user conditionally: `user_id = current_user&.id`
- provide a default guest user:

```
def current_user_with_default
  current_user || GuestUser.new
end
```